# Model a couple of simultaneously-determined variables

Tags: machine-learning

I would like to model the distribution of a couple of variables that are simultaneously determined.

Examples could be given by the couple (Demand, Offer) for a given product (these two are clearly jointly detemermined) or by the couple (Asked Wage, Duration of unemployment period) for a given person (the longer he/she waits, the less he/she can ask, but the more he/she asks, the longher he/she will wait).

I know that 2SLS (two-stage least squares, that uses instrumental variables) is a tool from econometrics for causal inference in this context, but what I am looking for is actually a ML algorithm/a probabilistic tool to estimate the joint distribution of the said couple and make predictions.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Why don't you predict one variable and then predict the second one based in the first prediction?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's because in this case I wouldn't take into account the fact that both are simultaneously determined... I'd like to model this process of simultaneous determination of the two variables.

Comment: I am not familiar with econometrics, but according to [random internet info](http://home.iitk.ac.in/~shalab/econometrics/Chapter17-Econometrics-SimultaneousEquationsModels.pdf), jointly determined variables are those that "are explained by the functioning of system and values of which are determined by the simultaneous interaction of the relations in the model are endogenous variables or jointly determined variables." Why can't they cannot be predicted as I suggested, by decomposing the joint probability: P(A, B) = P(A) P(B|A), so you first estimate A and then B conditioned on A's prediction?